# Graphical Backup on LTO4-tapedrive

Tags: software-recommendation, backup

I got a external Ultrium4 SAS-drive connected to a SAS-PCIe-card. Under Win10 and Ubuntu I can access the drive, rewind and eject the tape.

So, what would be a good solution to backup specific directories to the tape? Is there something with a GUI that keeps a database of the stored files on a per tape base? Since it is for my local photo-archive I don't have the money for business-software...

Comment: Please read this: https://wiki.debian.org/BackupAndRecovery and this https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools

Comment: Thank you :) Though it looks like the only way to backup that local PCs drives is to dump everything with TAR... :/ I tried it but the drive kept spinning up and down for every file.... is there a way to make sure the drive is fed with the right amount of data to keep the tapespeed steady?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se] ;-) Lemme call the attention of all the other old farts that remember tapes to this question. Together we should be able to figure this out.

Comment: @Fabby: LTO tapes are still in current uses, mainly for archiving

Comment: @cmak.fr I know. **0:-)**

Comment: As far as I see there is no real good way aside from dumping all with tar and copy the filelist to LibreCalc...? Funfact: LTO5 or newer is MUCH more usefriendly with the LTFS (LinearTapeFileSsystem) and can be used as a normal drive after formatting the tape.... sadly I own only LTO4 drives